# How to update field in the firebase firestore document using the collections

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

What I mean by using the collection is this:

```
 val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection(Constants.REDEEM_CODE)
            .whereEqualTo("key" , key)
            .update("x" , 0) // this  line is poping an error because there is no such method
```

I don't know the name of the document all I know is that documents have a field that is key and every document in that collection has a different key. That's the reason I'm trying to filter the documents using the where equal to method but now I don't know how to update the x field in that same document as I don't know the document file name ( which is set to auto-generate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the field `x` with the value of `0` inside each document that is returned by your query, please use the following lines of code:

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val codeRef = db.collection(Constants.REDEEM_CODE)
codeRef.whereEqualTo("key" , key).get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        for (document in task.result) {
            val update: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            update["x"] = 0
            codeRef.document(document.id).set(update, SetOptions.merge())
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot query the database and update the documents in a single go. You need to query the collection, get the documents, and right after that perform the update.

P.S. You are getting that error because [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#update(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)) method is **not** a function that exists inside the [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) class, but inside [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) class.

Comment: i have no  idea how it  is working, but it is working :)

Comment: It's working because `codeRef.document(document.id)` returns an object of type [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference), and on such an object you can defenetly call update().